# How do I group multiple polygons into the same record?

Tags: carto

I am trying to figure out how to group multiple polygons into the same record (using something like a spatial join tool) using CartoDB.

I'd prefer to keep the polygons as separate rather than joining them to create one larger polygon, but I need them to be part of the same record

Comment: didn't realize I could do this! I will take it into practice - thanks again, John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't currently possible to have collections of geometries in CartoDB. However, it is built on a relational database, so it isn't a problem to keep them separate.

**Table 1 multipolygons_table**

```
the_geom, group_id, etc
MULTIPOLYGON, SOME_INT
```

**Table 2 groups table**

```
group_id, etc
SOME_UNIQUE_INT
```

Then, just join the two using a dynamic query in your dashboard,

```
SELECT 
  ST_Collect(a.the_geom) the_geom, 
  ST_Collect(a.the_geom_webmercator) the_geom_webmercator, 
  b.group_id, 
  b.cartodb_id, 
  b.etc 
FROM table_1 a, table_2 b
WHERE 
  a.group_id = b.group_id
GROUP BY 
  b.group_id
```

Hope that helps.